# Quais os perigos de aceitar um merge de uma branch com commits behind?

Tags: git

Algumas vezes quando faço um **merge request** em um projeto, aparece que existem *commits behind*, entendo comigo que, isso acontece devido ao fato de na hora de criar minha branch, baseada na **branch** aonde irei criar o **merge request** depois, não havia alguns *commits* que foram criados depois, e no qual acabei não atualizando minha **branch** atual.

O que tentei exemplificar é o seguinte cenário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é, quais são os perigos de aceitar o merge da minha branch mesmo se houver *commits behind*?

Algumas vezes esses 'commits behind' são em outros arquivos que não os que eu alterei, tanto que não dá conflito na hora de criar o merge request

Se eu dar um merge, mesmo se os códigos do *commit behind* não afetarem o código que eu mexi, corro o risco de reescrever os códigos que foram criados nos *commit behind*?

Comment: Pelo que entendi da sua explicação, esse é o cenário mais comum do mundo do versionamento, não tem problema algum, se não tem conflito, basta fazer o merge, não é necessário sincronizar a branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É uma boa prática você fazer pull da branch pai da qual você quer abrir o merge request. Neste caso, "Master".

Em teoria não tem problema algum você abrir um merge request se não houver conflito, mas caso tenha, o git não vai fazer o merge automático e você precisará fazer o merge manual resolvendo os conflitos.

No entanto, um problema que pode ocorrer é que seu código pode não funcionar direito com as adições feitas em Master, e aí você só vai saber depois do merge. Se o merge ocorrer de forma automática, vai ser mais difícil detectar o problema. 

 
Por isso, é sempre recomendável que você faça o pull e teste as alterações antes de pedir o merge. Assim você garante que sua adição ao código não vai quebrar nada, e nada no código que está em Master vai quebrar o que você fez.

Answer (score 1):

> Minha dúvida é, quais são os perigos de aceitar o merge da minha
>   branch mesmo se houver commits behind?

O único problema seria se houvesse conflito entre código e você precisar corrigir manualmente, lembre-se, testar no final é sempre necessário.

Na pratica você deveria ter a branch develop e nela você vai dando o merge de todas as outras branchs e só depois fazer o merge no master (É aqui o resultado final do ciclo e não pode ter erros ou conflitos).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]